# Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler with separate navbar links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been making a fixed navbar that needs to have a navbar-toggler visible on all devices( I removed navbar-toggleable-md class to achieve that). It needs to be on the left, with the navbar-brand before it, while another set of links(outside of the toggler) need to be on the right.

Like this:

[image]

The thing is, no matter what I do, those right links refuse to stay inlined and my navbar goes into two rows.

Here's the basic outline of the code I've been working with. What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left ml-5" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <div class="float-right">
    <a>Link</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Someone, please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the navbar to `flex-row`. By default it's direction: column which will make the navbar elements stack vertically in 2 rows like you're seeing.

Also, put the extra link(s) after the Brand, and use `ml-auto` to push it to the right...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse flex-row flex-wrap">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left ml-5" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/CUCeeElIcI

Comment: This was it! Thanks, ZimSystem! You're a life saver!